# Developing a ws-bpel process using wso2 developer studio

Tags: web-services, wso2, apache-axis, bpel, business-application

I am developing a `ws-bpel` process using `wso2 developer studio` and I am following this [Tutorial](http://thiliniishaka.blogspot.fr/2012/10/develop-ws-bpel-process-using-wso2.html).

But when I want to deploy the `Bpel process on the BusinessProcessServer`, I am not able to test it. I get  an empty interface.

[image: Bpel delpoyment issue]

I must have the request message to send it. I don't have  any error in the bpel process when i generated it's `.zip` file.

Can any one help me please ?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like it is because you have secured the service with UTOverTransport. Try unsecuring the service (Re-secure it later if needed).

Comment: Thanks ! it is works but i have this response  ""<TryitClient xmlns="http://tryit.carbon.wso2.org">
   <Reason>Server connection has failed.</Reason>"""
</TryitClient> why i don't have the right response ???